# Multilevel indexing and computation using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, export-to-csv

I have an input file containts text as:

```
 case a1 b1.txt  c1.txt
 case a2 b2.txt  c2.txt
 case a3 b3.txt  c3.txt
```

where b1.tx,c1.txt,b2.txt,c2.txt,b3.txt, c3.txt are text files for reading the contents, while casea1,a2,a3 are cases.

cases are stored in an array.

I am reading txt file as:

```
bfile=[]
cfile=[]
f1= open(inp.txt,'r')
for line in f1:
    cases.append(line.split()[0])
    bfile.append(line.split()[1])
    cfile.append(line.split()[2])
```

Each file contains RED, GREEN BLUE strings and corresponding values. I am fetching those values from corresponding files and appending to arrays:
For b files, I am appending to b_red, b_green, b_blue.
For c files, appending to c_red,c_green,c_blue.

I have tried the corresponding code as:

```
b_red=[]
b_green=[]      
b_blue=[]
c_red=[]
c_green=[]  
c_blue=[]
for i in bfile:
f2=open(i,'r')
for line in f2.readlines():
    string=line
    if re.search(r'\bRED', string):
        redValue=float(string.split()[4])
        b_red.append(redValue)
        ---
        ---
for j in cfile:
f3= open(j, 'r')
for line in f3.readlines():
    string = line
    if re.search(r'\bRED', string):
        c_redValue=float(string.split()[4])
        c_red.append(c_redValue)
        ----
```

Therefore b_red=[120.0,10.0,100.0],c_red[120.0,9.0,20.0], likewise values are storing in arrays b_green, c_green,b_blue,c_blue.

What I have tried to ouput csv as:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'RED':b_red,'GREEN':b_green,'BLUE':b_blue })
df1.to_csv("OUT.CSV")
df2=pd.DataFrame({'RED':c_red,'GREEN':c_green,'BLUE':c_blue })
df2.to_csv("OUT.CSV")
df=df1-df2
df.to_csv("OUT.CSV")
```

Actually I want this:

```
             RED         GREEN       BLUE
a1  B       120.0         14.0        12.0
    C       120.0         17.0        14.0
    diff    0             -3          -2

a2  B       10.0          3.0         1.2   
    C       9.0           3.0         0.2
    diff    1.0           0           1.0

a3  B       100.0        15.0         10.0
    C       80.0         18.0         5.0
    diff    20.0         -3.0         5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

For the output, try this:

```
ff=open("OUT.CSV","w")
print(df,file=ff)
ff.close()
```

But, I think your requested output format is not really a csv.